# Deriving the Bohr radius of a hydrogen atom using Schrödinger's equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hydrogen

I'm trying to follow the book for the introduction to quantum mechanics by Griffiths. I'm following the part where he is solving Schrödinger's equation for the hydrogen atom. There, he found the Bohr radius, and he skipped over it. Here's what I mean:

He assumed that $k=\sqrt{\frac{-2mE}{\hbar}}$. That's fine. Then he found the energy level to be $E=\frac{me^4}{32\pi^2\varepsilon_0^2\hbar^2n^2}$, which is also fine. Then he assumed the $k=\frac{1}{an}$ after defining $\rho=kr$ and $\rho_0=\frac{me^2}{2\pi\varepsilon_0k\hbar^2}=2n$. The problem is, how did he get $k=\frac{1}{an}$? He just said that you should "combine" the above equations. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not really used Griffiths, but what I typically see is that one defines/derives the $2n=e^2k/E$ and $k=\sqrt{-2mE/\hbar^2}$ terms you have from the Schrodinger equation, then squares the $n$ term & substitutes,
$$
4n^2=\frac{e^4k^2}{E^2}=\frac{e^4}{E^2}\cdot-\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}
$$
to find that $E\propto1/n^2$. You can then use this definition of $E$ to determine $k$:
$$
k=\sqrt{-\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}}=\sqrt{-\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}\cdot-\frac{me^4}{2\hbar^2n^2}}=\frac{1}{an}
$$
where $a=\hbar^2/me^2$ is the Bohr radius. So I would say it is not an assumption, but a result of the derivation. A complete derivation in this fashion can be found at [Michael Fowler's page on the hydrogen atom](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/751.mf1i.fall02/HydrogenAtom.htm).